# Debian port(s) not responding

Tags: debian, iptables, linux-networking, fail2ban

I am fairly new to servers. I am trying to run a shoutcast server on debian. Shoutcast runs on a default port of 8000. My problem is it will not load when visiting xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000. When I log in via ssh, and create a tunnel to my local machine, it works just fine using localhost:8000. In my iptables I have added the following line:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 8000:9999 -j ACCEPT
```

A few days ago I installed fail2ban. Last night I uninstalled fail2ban using:

```
apt-get purge fail2ban
```

After doing so, it began to work. Now, I've re-installed fail2ban, and was looking for a way to configure it to ignore those ports. Again I know nothing about fail2ban and was learning how to use it.

After not getting it to work, I got frustrated and attempted to uninstall fail2ban once again. This time i used the command:

```
apt-get remove fail2ban
```

I understand the first one purges all config and restores iptables, hence why I chose that one. I ran the second command by mistake, instead of running purge.

I have since then re-installed fail2ban, and once again ran the purge command hoping it would clean and restore everything to the way it was. I still have no outside access and have to create a tunnel. I even removed the iptables files and restarted my server. Using

```
iptables -L
```

showed that I only have the default values to accept everything. I am finally at a loss here and don't know what else to check. I just want to be able to access xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000 to xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9999.

```
Results of: iptables -L -n -v


Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   2364  440K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  17177 2792K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    141  8308 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,10000
     28  1128 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 8000:9999    
    846 46996 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22    
      6   497 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
     57  3745 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "iptables denied: "
     57  3745 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   25350 7356K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Here is what I have

```
Results of: netstat -pnlt | grep ':8000'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3246/sc_serv
```

Comment: At the moment your firewall looks OK, is shoutcast listening to your public interface and not restricted to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @HBruijn the netstat -pnlt shows it's listening and bound to 0.0.0.0. Perhaps `iptables -t nat -L -vn` may show something?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses. The network admin had those ports blocked, hence why it worked via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to make your firewall rule stateful.

Like your working ssh rule, it should include `-m state --state NEW`.

You may also need to check for external firewalls, such as Amazon's "security groups" on EC2.